# Azure web app need restart to get latest changes?

Tags: docker, azure-web-app-service, azure-container-registry

I have an azure web app service, code publish is Azure Container Registry. Everything works fine, but only thing is that every time push image with changes, nothing is reflected in web app until I restart service. Is it possible to have  changes reflected without restarting web app?

Comment: No, not as far as I know.

Comment: No, but you can automate the process, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-ci-cd-custom-container?tabs=acr&pivots=container-linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have followed the below steps to repro in my test environment and got positive results.

Step 1: Create ACR and Azure web app
Step 2: Enable Admin User in ACR.

[image]

Step 3: Build a Docker file and push it to ACR as below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Please find the commands used in the above screenshots

```
$docker build -t <image-name>:<tag>
$docker tag <image-name>:<tag> <acr-login-server>/<image-name>:<tag>
$docker login <acr-login-server>
$docker push <acr-login-server>/<image-name>:<tag>
```

Verify it in Container Registry.

[image]

Step 4: Modify the deployment centre settings in the webapp as shown below.

[image]

[image]

Copy the Webhook URL and navigate to the ACR > webhook > create new webhook and paste it into Service URI.

[image]

Step 5: Access the Webapp URL and verify.

[image]

Step 6: Modify the code and rebuild the docker file and push it to ACR to verify CD.

[image]

****Note: Sometimes it might take 2 mins to get reflect new changes in the webapp***